# $\mathbb Z$ is the smallest ordered ring with $0\neq 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers, axioms

I read [this relevant thread on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23193/axiomatic-definition-of-integers#:%7E:text=DEFINITION%20Integers%20(i.e.%20the%20system,x%E2%88%921%E2%87%92x%3D1)), but it didn't quite contain the characterization I was looking for. My question is: Suppose that we define $\mathbb Z$ to be an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) with $0\neq 1$ and the property that $\mathbb Z$ is its smallest subring. Is this already enough to define the integers up to some ring-isomorphism? If someone can sketch or refer to a full proof, that would be great.

Comment: Let $\Bbb A$ such a ring. Then the condition that it's ordered and $0\ne 1$ is enough to show that $n\cdot 1\in\Bbb A$ for all natural integer $n$, and that these elements are distinct. Then you need the negative counterpart, so $\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb A$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Or maybe even $\Bbb Z\subseteq A$.

Comment: @Arthur Depends on the [notational convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#%E2%8A%82_and_%E2%8A%83_symbols). I was trained with $\subset$ meaning *subset* and not necessarily *proper subset*. Not sure what's preferred on MSE.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut And anyone who uses $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ in a way that doesn't reflect $<$ and $\leq$ uses subpar notation. There is no reason those shouldn't correspond, and plenty of reasons they should (I can think of at least two, those being ease of reading since symbols that look the same mean the same, and aesthetic: $\subsetneq$ is just uglier than the others). Training can be overcome.

Comment: Well, I respect your opinion, but being a notation, it's not more than an opinion, even though your argument is rather well-funded. Both are in use, and I prefer $\subset$, so for the time being, I will continue to use it if you don't mind. But I'll be more careful on MSE to at least indicate the meaning. Likewise I prefer $A^T$ over $^tA$, and $C_n^k$ over $n\choose k$ (but the latter on MSE, much more frequent), and for the composition of permutations I don't really have a preference, as I read authors using one or the other.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut AFAIU, you suggest to consider a different definition of $\mathbb Z$ and then to show that $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb A$ are isomorphic. So this sounds like you think that my definition works, am I right?

Comment: Not isomorphic. $\Bbb A$ may be $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$, for instance. But we know for sure $\Bbb Z$ (or something isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$) must be a subset of $\Bbb A$ (and $\Bbb A$ may be equal to $\Bbb Z$, of course).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut $\mathbb R$ is not its smallest subring, is it?

Comment: I don't understand your question: $\Bbb R$ would be the smallest subring of what?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut $\mathbb R$ is **not** the smallest subring of itself, that's what I was saying. One part of my definition of $\mathbb Z$ is that $\mathbb Z$ is the smallest subring of itself.

Comment: That's what is proved here. As it's true for any ring $\Bbb A$, it's also true for $\Bbb A=\Bbb Z$. I.e., a nontrivial subring of $\Bbb Z$ must be itself.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut "As it's true for any ring..." - What is true for any ring?

Comment: Sorry, it was sloppy. It's true for any ring $\Bbb A$ that if it's an order ring and $0\ne 1$, $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb A$. Now let $\Bbb A=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This is subtle, but did you purposely say "...for any ring...if it's an ordered ring" instead of "...for any ordered ring..."?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I mean, is there at most one ordering for each ring?

Comment: Wasn't on purpose, but I think it's equivalent.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut [I don't think so](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4583362/572841) ;)