# Let $R$ be a ring. Is there at most one ordering $\leq$ such that $(R,\leq)$ is an ordered ring?

Tags: ring-theory, ordered-fields

I was wondering whether it is equivalent to consider an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) or a ring that can be ordered. I assume that there are plenty of people who already thought about this issue, hence my question...I would also like to know if the existence of a multiplicative identity is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even for fields, there are usually many (potentially infinitely many) non-equivalent orderings. For instance, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has the "obvious" ordering coming from its embedding into $\mathbb{R}$, but you can also embed it into $\mathbb{R}$ by sending $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$, and this embedding induces a different ordering on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

In general, for a field $K$, the orderings of $K$ form a compact topological space $X(K)$ (the so-called *space of orderings*, with its *Harrison topology*), which can also be described as the generic fiber of $Spec(W(K))\to Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ where $W(K)$ is the Witt ring of $K$ (this is called Artin-Schreier theory).

Comment: You have the embedding $\varphi: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}$, and then you define $x\leqslant y$ by $\varphi(x)\leqslant \varphi(y)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. So with this new order $\sqrt{2}$ is negative.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation! Okay, if $1$ was negative, then something would have been off (AFAIK we have $0\leq 1$ for all ordered rings), but this makes sense.

Comment: Are we sure that this is not only an ordering, but an ordering that makes it an ordered ring?

Comment: This is what "ordering" means; not just a random order relation, but one that makes the ring into an ordered ring. And yes, I'm sure, feel free to check the axioms!

Comment: "This is what "ordering" means; not just a random order relation, but one that makes the ring into an ordered ring." - I was about to ask this, thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: That second paragraph really sounds interesting to me. But when I go research it in wikipedia, I find two things: [Artin-Schreier theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory) related to Galois theory, and [Artin-Schreier theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) related to real-closed fields which sounds like it has a better chance of being related.  I think the discussions in wikipedia probably aren't good enough to reach your summary, though.  Can you confirm you're referring to the second one?